# Can I develop a game using C++ and deploy to XBOX 360?

Tags: xna, c++, xbox

I'm a C# developer and an enthusiast of XNA, but I'm really disappointed with the game engines available for XNA.

I was using Torque X, which is really good, but GarageGames no longer supports Torque X for XNA 4.1. I searched for other engines, but only the sunburn was worth it and would have to pay - I already spent money with Torque.

Based on this, I'm thinking about starting to develop in C++. **Can I develop with some C++ engines and deploy to XBox 360?**

Comment: did you try Flat Red Ball? It uses Glue (GUI tool), so it wasn't my cup of tea, but you may like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple answer. No. Unless you are a licensed developer with Microsoft (which costs thousands) then you will not be able to deploy C++ applications to the Xbox 360.

There might be some homebrew software out there somewhere to try and do it, but a) it's a legally grey area and b) it's more than likely to be completely subpar in handling the console's hardware capabilities.

EDIT: Just to add about engines. There are plenty of engines out there that support Xbox 360 as a development platform (Unity, Unreal Engine, etc) but they all have the precursor that you have a developer license.

Comment: Hey Ray, thanks for the answer. 
But I forgot to mention that I'm wanna develop 2d games, and Unity, Unreal and the most of engines that I saw I focused on 3d (yes, I can develop 2d with them, but, It's really bad).

Comment: Even so, unfortunately there is no way to deploy C++ applications, regardless of whether they are 2D or 3D, onto the 360 (or any console for that matter, without using homebrew SDKs). For the Xbox specifically, XNA and C# are your only options for the moment.

Comment: Doesnt XNA game studio support C++ ? Whatever happens you'll have to use a .Net compiler but there's no reason why you can't use any .Net supported language surely.

Comment: XNA Game Studio does not support C++

Comment: @Murphy A good strategy would be to release games on PC first, but targeting the XBox on the code and control features. Then show it to microsoft, or at least try to be successful on PC. Once you have at least one title that shows you can do it, you have better chances to get a contract with Microsoft. That said, you should then keep pushing on PC (maybe on Steam).

Answer (score 0):

You can, however, you must use proper Devkit, which is hard but not impossible. Just, apply for ID@XBOX and go learn it yourself.

And seriously, target steam first and show some traction. Or, pay a lot of bucks. Or, port to C# and go for it.

Answer (score -4):

Any language will run on Xbox 360. There are games available that were programmed in C++ and Java. For example Google 'Minecraft Xbox 360 Edition Minecraft wiki'. It will say Minecraft for Xbox was written in C# and C++.

Comment: Yes...With a developer license, which the OP is probably not able to afford.

Comment: 1. The Xbox 360 cannot support *any* language
2. I am 99% sure it does not support Java
3. Java 3D is not a language
4. I'm unsure whether you meant to say "nut heads" or "butt heads". To be fair, butt heads is hilarious.

Comment: this answer seems useful in its' current form, no?