# How to develop XBox 360 games?

Tags: xna-4.0, xbox

I understand that I can learn XNA as a hobbyist, but for top games like Fifa for example how are they witten?

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29289/can-i-develop-a-game-using-c-and-deploy-to-xbox-360

Comment: I guess I don't see how this question is constructive.

Comment: @byte56 it is a request for information on the steps to follow to develop a "top game" for a console (I think the OP more means physical game), and if it were abstracted down to the general case of "How would I develop a physical game for a console" then it is rather constructive, and using the Xbox360 as an example this could actually be quite constructive/beneficial.

Comment: "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical..." It is none of these things. So sad that a google search led me to another one of these pointless closed questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to develop a game via physical media for a console (XBox360, PS3, Wii) you would need to contact the respective company (Xbox360->Microsoft, PS3->Sony, Wii->nintendo), and request/purchase  a dev-kit (this is not a small request/purchase, and some of these companies may request that you formally pitch your game)

this dev-kit is in many cases a system that has some of the features either removed, modified, or added (in the case of addition this is for the ability to debug, and to easily get information from the system), and can also give rights to the user that are not given to a user of the actual system. in other cases the dev-kit is a software-library/emulator for testing the executable on.

few if any console developer(s) give these dev-kits to anyone who asks, and it requires a non-disclosure agreement (for anyone to work on the project).

if your more asking about language, and dev-environment that can be different from system to system, but is a fair question when you contact to request a dev-kit. as a side note: these dev-kits are usually per title, and need to be re-requested/re-purchased for each title.

Answer (score 2):

This big companys just buy the Xbox 360 SDK from Microsoft. I think its a huge Library written in C++.

Comment: What is the compiler used?

Comment: i think its to 100% visual studio.

Comment: what could this library contain that the original game would not?